# Fancybox plugin for WordPress does not work

Tags: jquery, wordpress, fancybox

someone can help me with Fancybox for WordPress?
I put this code in the page:

```
<div id="galleria-cucina">[gallery ids="283,282,281,280,279"]</div>
<p style="text-align: center;"><a class="fancybox" href="#galleria-cucina">GUARDA FOTO GALLERY</a></p>
```

But when i click on the "a" link does not show any image, but only a blank small overlay white box.

What's wrong?

Thank you

Comment: open developer tools and in console, is any js error present

Comment: I have checked with google inspector and there are no js errors

Comment: Using EasyFancybox? ask for help to the author here https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/easy-fancybox